# Stripe checkout session is missing metadata

Tags: python, flask, stripe-payments

I have been trying to pass metadata through `stripe.checkout.Session.create()` like so:

```
stripe.api_key = STRIPE_SECRET_KEY

payments_blueprint = Blueprint('payments', __name__, url_prefix='/payments')


@payments_blueprint.route('/checkout', methods=['POST'])
def create_checkout_session():

    try:
        checkout_session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
            metadata=dict(key='val'),
            payment_method_types=['card'],
            line_items=request.form.get("lineItems", LINE_ITEMS),
            success_url=f'{request.environ["HTTP_ORIGIN"]}/success',
            cancel_url=f'{request.environ["HTTP_ORIGIN"]}/cancel',
            mode='payment'
        )

        return redirect(checkout_session.url, code=HTTPStatus.SEE_OTHER)

    except stripe.error.InvalidRequestError as err:
        return redirect(f'{request.environ["HTTP_ORIGIN"]}/error', code=HTTPStatus.MOVED_PERMANENTLY)
```

and neither the responses from stripe nor the events passing through my webhook contains any metadata, even though the event logs in the stripe console for the request and the response both contain:

```
  "metadata": {
    "key": "val"
  },...
```

I am listening to all events using `stripe listen --forward-to localhost:8000/hooks/ --print-json` and all that the endpoint at /hooks does is print the event to stdout. nothing else.

I would like for this metadata to be passed through my series of booking validation webhooks. referencing this:

https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-metadata

Basically i am following these docs, sending metadata through the call for `checkout.Session.create()`, and then not seeing this metadata. I have tried using the `dict()` constructor, using dict syntax instead (`{"key":"val"}`), creating a variable and setting it to this dict before passing it through the function, and every other way i could think of to pass this metadata dictionary in, but i have not been getting it back from stripe.

Here is the hook i have set up where these events are being forwarded:

```
class TestHook(Resource):

    def post(self):
        event = stripe.Event.construct_from(
            json.loads(request.data),
            stripe.api_key
        ).to_dict()

        print(event['type'])
        pprint(event['data']['object'])
```

And the output to stdout:

```
payment_intent.created
{'amount': 20000,
 'amount_capturable': 0,
 'amount_received': 0,
 'application': None,
 'application_fee_amount': None,
 'canceled_at': None,
 'cancellation_reason': None,
 'capture_method': 'automatic',
 'charges': {},
 'client_secret': 'pi_3JTYxxxx7t',
 'confirmation_method': 'automatic',
 'created': 1630184808,
 'currency': 'usd',
 'customer': None,
 'description': None,
 'id': 'pi_3JTYxxxxVm4',
 'invoice': None,
 'last_payment_error': None,
 'livemode': False,
 'metadata': <StripeObject at 0x105c061d0> JSON: {},
 'next_action': None,
 'object': 'payment_intent',
 'on_behalf_of': None,
 'payment_method': None,
 'payment_method_options': {'card': {'installments': None,
                                     'network': None,
                                     'request_three_d_secure': 'automatic'}},
 'payment_method_types': ['card'],
 'receipt_email': None,
 'review': None,
 'setup_future_usage': None,
 'shipping': None,
 'source': None,
 'statement_descriptor': None,
 'statement_descriptor_suffix': None,
 'status': 'requires_payment_method',
 'transfer_data': None,
 'transfer_group': None}

checkout.session.completed
{'allow_promotion_codes': None,
 'amount_subtotal': 20000,
 'amount_total': 20000,
 'automatic_tax': {'enabled': False,
                   'status': None},
 'billing_address_collection': None,
 'cancel_url': 'http://localhost:9000/#/guides/cozumel-buzos-del-caribe/trips/7-day-dive?cancelpayment=true',
 'client_reference_id': None,
 'currency': 'usd',
 'customer': 'cus_K7oxxxguu',
 'customer_details': {'email': 'abc@gmail.com',
                      'tax_exempt': 'none',
                      'tax_ids': []},
 'customer_email': None,
 'id': 'cs_test_b1Yxxx9dM',
 'livemode': False,
 'locale': None,
 'metadata': <StripeObject at 0x103d64a40> JSON: {},
 'mode': 'payment',
 'object': 'checkout.session',
 'payment_intent': 'pi_3JTYxxxVm4',
 'payment_method_options': <StripeObject at 0x103d648b0> JSON: {},
 'payment_method_types': ['card'],
 'payment_status': 'paid',
 'setup_intent': None,
 'shipping': None,
 'shipping_address_collection': None,
 'submit_type': None,
 'subscription': None,
 'success_url': 'http://localhost:9000/#/payment/success',
 'total_details': {'amount_discount': 0,
                   'amount_shipping': 0,
                   'amount_tax': 0},
 'url': None}
```

in all these events metadata is `'metadata': <StripeObject at 0x103d64a40> JSON: {}`

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by the response? Are you referring to the response to `stripe.checkout.Session.create`, the event generated as a webhook, the frontend response to the redirect, the related PaymentIntent, something else? Also, please provide an example response.

Comment: I meant the payload does not contain metadata. in the event in the hook or in the response from `checkout.session.create`.

{"api_version":"2020-08-27","created":1629860910,"data":{"object":...,"metadata":{},...}

Comment: If the metadata isn't set in the request payload, then you'r likely providing a null value from `dict(key='val')`. Could you add the exact request body that shows in the Stripe request logs to your original question to confirm if that's the case?

Comment: dict(key='val') will not return null

>>> dict(key='val')
{'key': 'val'}

Comment: Sure, but what does the corresponding request body look like (the exact body) in the Stripe request log?

Comment: "metadata": {
    "key": "val"
  }, is contained in the request body

Comment: what is the error log or api response? is it possible to add that?

Comment: Theres no error log as I'm just testing a successful payment (4242 4242 4242 4242). The API response has no metadata for any of the events which spawn from this

Comment: I edited the question to include more output to show what metadata is set to, as well as the hook so you can see that i don't actually manipulate the event contents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What exactly do you mean by "session response" here? Can you provide an example?

For the webhook, which exact event `type` are you subscribed to? If, for example, you're listening to `payment_intent.succeeded` instead of `checkout.session.completed`, then it would be expected for the *session* `metadata` to not be present. You can optionally provide `metadata` to the underlying payment intent using `payment_intent_data[metadata][key]=val`, which would then be included in the payment intent event bodies.

https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-payment_intent_data-metadata

Comment: Yes that is the documentation i used (mentioned in my original question). I am listening to all events (running `stripe listen --forward-to localhost:8000/hooks/ --print-json`). None of these events contain the metadata I have passed in the initial call to `checkout.Session.create()`. editing the question again for more clarity about what i mean.

Comment: Are you sure about that? Listening to _all_ events is usually not recommended. You'd receive many evens, and all but one would be expected to *not* have that metadata. Only `checkout.session.completed` will have that metadata. Trying adding the specific event to the listen command and looking only at those: `stripe listen --events=checkout.session.completed`

Comment: i am listening to all events just to track where the metadata disappears. in practice, i will have separate hooks set up for different events, and based on the event i will update a database of bookings and reservations

Comment: yes i am sure about it. i took your advice and listened only to the checkout.session.completed event, and metadata is not there. empty object

Comment: I added the code for my hook to the question above as well as the output of it so you can see that metadata is not being manipulated at all

Comment: OK then I'd suggest writing in to Stripe's support team with example request IDs ( https://stripe.com/docs/api/request_ids ) so that they can look at what's going on here.

Comment: Be sure to come back and share an update once this is solved!

Comment: Oh wow you think this might be something Stripe is mishandling? I was wondering if I was doing something really dumb or if I was going crazy

Comment: wasnt a problem with stripe. was me. not sure what i did differently as i refactored the function. if i find out what the issue was with my code. i'll post it. thanks for the help! I'm giving you the bounty

Comment: Glad you got it figured out! So it was what I suspected (payment intent events etc not getting that metadata) _plus_ the other issue you described affecting the Checkout session itself. It happens!

Comment: Just wanted to reiterate the last bit of my answer, that you _can_ configure metadata to be attached to the payment intent (and charge) underneath the session by using the `payment_intent_data[metadata]` parameter. This is a distinct set of metadata from the session itself. If you set metadata here, then events such as `payment_intent.succeeded` _would_ have that metadata included.

Comment: oh is that so? is the payment intent itself a substructure in the checkout session?

Comment: In payment mode, yes: https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-payment_intent
And some (but not all) payment intent parameters are exposed as pass-through via `payment_intent_data`.

Answer (score 18):

This question has been answered but since the answers weren't immediately clear to me until further experimentation, I'm just proposing a little extra information for anyone having similar issues.

In the Session creation snippet below, pay attention to the TWO metadata declarations:

```
stripe.checkout.Session.create(
  success_url=success_url,
  cancel_url=cancel_url,
  payment_method_types=["card"],
  mode="payment",
  metadata={
    "foo": "FOO",
  },
  payment_intent_data={
    "metadata": {
      "bar": "BAR",
    }
  },
  line_items=[
    {
      "name": product_name,
      "quantity": quantity,
      "currency": currency,
      "amount": unit_price,
    },
  ]
)
```

To test Webhooks, I used the command `stripe listen --forward-to localhost:/webhook` via the Stripe CLI and obtained the following results from a successful payment transaction with my app. This is what I observed:

- My 'FOO' data was available in the payload received from the webhook callback for `checkout.session.completed` only.
- My 'BAR' data was available in the payload received from the webhook callback for `payment_intent.created`, `payment_intent.succeeded`, and `charge.succeeded` only.
- Neither 'FOO' nor 'BAR' were available in `customer.created` or `customer.updated`.

Comment: is that so? you can add payment intent metadata on the call to create a checkout session?

Comment: It's annoying that you have to pass the meta data through in two places/twice during `stripe.checkout.Session.create` but this seems to work (in test mode so far) and allows me to set for example an order number right at the very beginning and identify it right through to the end.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I have now spent hours trying to pass the metadata to a stripe session and receive it with the 'checkout.session.completed'.

Answer (score 1):

After spending some time with stripe folks on their discord (they are super helpful) i discovered that metadata posted to the checkout session, using the method described in the question, should persist but only in the checkout session flow. it would not be present on any other events (namely charge, paymentIntent, or other flows). After refactoring my code, i managed to see this metadata on the `checkout_session.complete` event, so as anticipated... i did something dumb. An important thing to note though, is that this metadata would not be seen on any subsequent events other than the checkout session, which is something i did not understand at first. The fact that the metadata was not on subsequent *checkout session* events was due to a problem between the chair and the keyboard, and i wont ask any further questions for a while.

big thanks to everyone who tried to answer and who directed me to stripe. this actually opened up a can of worms, in a good way.