# Stripe Webhook doesnt capture product data/meta data

Tags: stripe-payments, metadata, webhooks

I want to use stripe payment link system, The payment method can be Card/Wallet

I dont want to use checkout button system, since the payment isnt dynamic

Once the payment is successful (auto subscription or manual checkout) I need to send the activation code to the users email. The next year when the charge is auto debited from card I need to generate the activation key again and send the same for the next year.

I see there are many events in the Stripe payment webhooks, I have used **charge.succeeded** event listener and it does send me the object (pasted below).

I have one issue here. If I rely on this charge.succeeded object I find no information on which product the purchase is made. There are many products in my system

The response have user supplied email but there is no way I product details in the **charge.succeeded** object. I have supplied the metadata info in the payment link page as below. I have also supplied the metadata in products as well as metadata in the every pricings

[image]

I use this link - https://buy.stripe.com/test_28o3cn6hC5bgdoIcMM
Test card number: 4242 4242 4242 4242
and any dates and CVV number would work.

Webhook responses are captured here - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RjnFnjHvs9ca8tIPoRiNHFUph_npm5pVK2S15wVllzI/edit?usp=sharing

Any help is greatly appreciated

```
{
  "id": "evt_1KWzCbHpIo9Nhh5aYEv7XlY8",
  "object": "event",
  "api_version": "2017-12-14",
  "created": 1645777861,
  "data": {
    "object": {
      "id": "ch_1KWzCaHpIo9Nhh5atK09dpaO",
      "object": "charge",
      "amount": 100,
      "amount_captured": 100,
      "amount_refunded": 0,
      "application": null,
      "application_fee": null,
      "application_fee_amount": null,
      "balance_transaction": "txn_1KWzCaHpIo9Nhh5anEebLs4X",
      "billing_details": {
        "address": {
          "city": null,
          "country": "IN",
          "line1": null,
          "line2": null,
          "postal_code": null,
          "state": null
        },
        "email": "te...@email.com",
        "name": "CARDNAME",
        "phone": null
      },
      "calculated_statement_descriptor": "XXXXXXXXXXX",
      "captured": true,
      "created": 1645777860,
      "currency": "inr",
      "customer": "cus_LDQ2DBhL2VkPOH",
      "description": "Subscription creation",
      "destination": null,
      "dispute": null,
      "disputed": false,
      "failure_code": null,
      "failure_message": null,
      "fraud_details": {
      },
      "invoice": "in_1KWzCYHpIo9Nhh5ammBkFvU1",
      "livemode": false,
      "metadata": {
      },
      "on_behalf_of": null,
      "order": null,
      "outcome": {
        "network_status": "approved_by_network",
        "reason": null,
        "risk_level": "normal",
        "risk_score": 58,
        "seller_message": "Payment complete.",
        "type": "authorized"
      },
      "paid": true,
      "payment_intent": "pi_1KWzCYHpIo9Nhh5aj6Xgl3tS",
      "payment_method": "pm_1KWzCXHpIo9Nhh5aADMKyWPc",
      "payment_method_details": {
        "card": {
          "brand": "visa",
          "checks": {
            "address_line1_check": null,
            "address_postal_code_check": null,
            "cvc_check": "pass"
          },
          "country": "US",
          "exp_month": 2,
          "exp_year": 2022,
          "fingerprint": "MxtsbEBU2BmJbOn4",
          "funding": "credit",
          "installments": null,
          "last4": "4242",
          "network": "visa",
          "three_d_secure": null,
          "wallet": null
        },
        "type": "card"
      },
      "receipt_email": null,
      "receipt_number": null,
      "receipt_url": "https://pay.stripe.com/receipts/acct_1BhpF1HpIo9Nhh5a/ch_1KWzCaHpIo9Nhh5atK09dpaO/rcpt_LDQ2FDPK6fwsEyBOISiDCItSv8JeNbl",
      "refunded": false,
      "refunds": {
        "object": "list",
        "data": [

        ],
        "has_more": false,
        "total_count": 0,
        "url": "/v1/charges/ch_1KWzCaHpIo9Nhh5atK09dpaO/refunds"
      },
      "review": null,
      "shipping": null,
      "source": null,
      "source_transfer": null,
      "statement_descriptor": null,
      "statement_descriptor_suffix": null,
      "status": "succeeded",
      "transfer_data": null,
      "transfer_group": null
    }
  },
  "livemode": false,
  "pending_webhooks": 1,
  "request": {
    "id": "req_QzrolSFU0OA7D7",
    "idempotency_key": "228c5670-85ea-4047-9f9f-9d1e519ffc2c"
  },
  "type": "charge.succeeded"
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I have had a similar problem when using a webhook solution in Stripe. Although I had defined meta data in the product it was not shipped, i.e. *metadata* in JSON was empty.

In my case the solution has been to use the meta data of the price instead (which is defined within the product). For this, just click price section on product page on Stripe website...

[image]

...and define meta data on the price page.

[image]

There is another interesting post https://stackoverflow.com/a/69117489/10849985 showing that it is event-depending if meta data is provided or not, i.e. some events linked to the webhook inlcude it, others not.

Answer (score 1):

a Checkout Session will be generated under the hood when your customer opens a Payment Link. Therefore, you should listen to the [checkout.session.completed](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-checkout.session.completed) events, and get the product data from the [line_items](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-line_items) property of the Checkout Session object.

Comment: will the checkout.session.completed response also sent the next year when the card is charged automatically during the subscription?

Comment: Which event will be fired when the subscription auto debits the card?

Comment: You can listen to invoice.paid (https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-invoice.paid) events. They will be fired upon successful subscription renewals.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was that I was merging the price and products objects together which was overwriting the metadata on the product with the empty metadata of the price object.

To fix this I just made sure the metadata was receiving the values from the product obj

```
    const product = await stripe.products.list();
    const price = await stripe.prices.list();
    const productData = product.data.map((productData, index) => {
      return { 
        ...productData, 
        ...price.data[index], 
        quantity: 1, 
        addedToCart: false,
        metadata: productData.metadata };
    });
```